# Como Incluir e Referenciar .JS no meu projeto?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Bem é o seguinte, tenho um arquivo .JS no meu projeto.

Estou chamando ele no HEAD ASSIM:

```
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="~/JS/validacao.js"></script>
```

dentro desse validação.JS tem uma função de mascara.

e coloquei no Textbox o seguinte evento.

```
this.TxtCEP.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "Mascara(CEP, TxtCEP);");

<asp:TextBox ID="TxtCEP" runat="server" style="margin-left: 66px" Width="231px" TextMode="Number" MaxLength ="8"></asp:TextBox>
```

Função Mascara

```
   function Mascara(formato, objeto) {
campo = eval (objeto);
// CEP
if (formato=='CEP'){
    var CodCar = event.keyCode;
    if (CodCar < 48 || CodCar > 57) {
        campo.focus();
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
    separador = '-'; 
    conjunto1 = 5;
    if (campo.value.length == conjunto1) {
        campo.value = campo.value + separador;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não está funcionando.

estou fazendo certo ?

Comment: posta tambem a funcao Mascara

Comment: aperta f12 e olhe o console e poste os erros tbm

Comment: você tem que usar assim src="~/JS/validacao.js" onde o `~` seria a pasta root do seu projeto.

Comment: Como está sua estrutura de pastas? a pasta JS está na raiz do projeto, ou está dentro de outra pasta? Muito provavelmente você tenha uma pasta script e a JS esteja dentro dela, ai sua referência tem que ser assim `src="~/script/JS/validacao.js"`, lembrando que o `~` é definido como root operator pelo asp.net

Comment: o path ta errado segue a solucao do @PabloTondolodeVargas

Comment: Já troquei, mesmo assim nada.

Comment: Atualiza a pergunta com as modificações que você fez e com a mensagem de erro que está dando agora

Comment: primeiramente não me dei conta que era webforms, segunda mente estou adicionando a respostaaaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em projeto web forms, para adicionar a referência a um script, você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="Scripts/JS/validacao.js"></script>
```

No entando, prefiro fazer da seguinte mandeira

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/JS/validacao.js")%>"></script>
```

Assim eu garanto que se eu publicar o projeto em uma subpasta do domínio principal, ele irá pegar a referência correta ao meu *script*

Outro detalhe que você está errando, é na hora de atribuir o evento ao seu compoente, essa é a forma correta que fiz no exemplo que publiquei em meu [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/IncluirReferenciaJS)

```
this.TxtCEP.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", $"Mascara('CEP', {this.TxtCEP.ClientID});");
```

A diferença para o seu, é que estou passando o CEP como *string* e utilizando o [*ClientID*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) que obtém o identificador do controle gerado pelo ASP.NET.